# How to automatically create a tarball from differences in directories?

Tags: linux, tar, difftool

I have a situation where I have 2 large directory trees, an `old` and a `new`.  Most files are the same, but some are different and/or missing in the old version.  I would like to find a way to automatically create a tar file that contains:
a) all files in `new` that are not in `old`
b) all files that are different between `new` and `old`

Files that only exist in `old` should be ignored.  Symbolic links need to be maintained.  "Different" needs to be determined by a full binary comparison.
As you might guess, I'm trying to create a patch to get one tree to match another. Maybe there is already a tool to do this, or perhaps I need to string together some commands.
I'm am working in Ubuntu Linux.

Comment: Does it have to be a tarball? I'm thinking of `rsync --read-batch`...

Comment: It needs to be a tarball eventually, but creating a tree with the changed files could be a good intermediate stage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found some ideas on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6217628/diff-to-output-only-the-file-names) on how to get a list of the files that are different.  I went with an rsync approach with the `--dry-run` option:

```
rsync -rv --dry-run --size-only --links old/ new/
```

Once I had the list of files, I invoked tar with those files.  This didn't totally solve the issue of differentiating files only in 1 place vs. the other, but with some manual intervention, I got it to work.  I wish I could have gotten to a fully automated solution, but I was able to solve my immediate problem with these general steps.